# Create array of COM-objects in VB6

Tags: arrays, com, vb6

I have a COM object which is available by executing `CreateObject("COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job")`. So far this works fine and I'm able to declare all the required properties. But I fail while trying to create an array of objects with the class `COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job` in VisualBasic 6. I need this array to be passed to the method `SendJobs` by `COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.StorageSystemManager`. The code fails when declaring the array of objects like `Dim Jobs(1) As COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job`.

```
Set Job = CreateObject("COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job")
Job.JobIdentification = "JOB02_VB6"

' Invalid code declaring the array of COM objects
Dim Jobs(1) As COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job
Jobs(0) = Job

Set StorageSystemManager = CreateObject("COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.StorageSystemManager")
StorageSystemManager.SendJobs (Jobs)
```

It works fine if i'm not using a array and passing the `Job` object to a method named `StorageSystemManager.SendJob(Job)` so the error must be in the array declaration.

On executing this script the error "User defined type not defined" is thrown by Visual Basic (pointing to the mentioned line of array declaration).

I tried declaring the array without any type declaration, with `Variant` and `Object`. All resulting in 'Error 13: Incompatible Types' since the `SendJobs` method is expecting an array of `COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job`.

```
Dim Jobs(1)
Dim Jobs(1) As Variant
Dim Jobs(1) As Object
```

Comment: Can you try `Dim Jobs(1) As Object`?

Comment: tried that, no success :(

Comment: Have you added a reference to the DLL hosting COMPANYNAMESPACE.COM.Models.Job ?

Comment: Do you have to use Late Binding?  You might have better luck with Early Binding.

Comment: `tried that, no success` - it would appear you label errors of any nature as "no success". An object returned by `CreateObject` can always be stored in a variable of type `Object` or (obviously) in an element of an array of type `Object`.

Comment: Possibly `Set Jobs(0) = Job`?  Since these would be reference types, `Set` would normally be necessary.  You are also being unclear as to when you have a compile error vs a runtime error.  And what the error message is exactly.

Comment: It very much depends how your method SendJobs is declared precisely. Do you have a .TLB or better an .IDL (use OleView from SDK) that would describe this method for us? Also have your tried `StorageSystemManager.SendJobs Jobs` w/o parens

Comment: If you created that COM library using .NET and exported the type lib from it using RegAsm, my guess is the class name is actually `COMPANYNAMESPACE_COM_Models.Job.  Have you added a reference to the library using the VB6 IDE?

Comment: Remove extra parentheses on last SendJob call and use Set Jobs(0) = expr with Set for references.

Comment: ´StorageSystemManager.SendJobs (Jobs)` <- This is not how you pass an array. You pass an array like `Call MyFunc(Jobs())` I'd also like to see the definition of `StorageSystemManager.SendJobs` from the Object Inspector (F2). And to add a word of advice: make it a habit to truly specify the array boundaries, i.e. `Dim Jobs(0 To 1)` instead of `Dim Jobs(1)`.